# Gradient of $a^T X b$ with respect to $X$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

How can I find the gradient of the term $a^TXb$ where $X$ is a $n \times m$ matrix, and $a$ and $b$ are column vectors.  Since the gradient is with respect to a matrix, it should be a matrix.  But I do not have a clue on how to derive this gradient.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the function in terms of the inner/Frobenius product (which I'll denote by a colon).  Then finding the differential and gradient is straightforward
$$\eqalign{
 f &= ab^T:X \cr\cr
df &= ab^T:dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= ab^T \cr\cr
}$$
Note that the inner product is really just an infix notation for the trace 
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$f ( {\bf X} ) := {\bf a}^{\top} {\bf X} \, {\bf b} = \mbox{tr} \left( {\bf a}^{\top} {\bf X} \, {\bf b} \right) = \mbox{tr} \left( {\bf b} {\bf a}^{\top} {\bf X} \right) = \left\langle {\bf a} {\bf b}^{\top}, {\bf X} \right\rangle$$

where the [cyclic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property) of the trace was used and $\langle \cdot \,, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product). Since scalar field $f$ is linear in $\bf X$, its gradient is simply

$$\nabla f ( {\bf X} ) = \color{blue}{{\bf a} {\bf b}^{\top}}$$

---

[matrix-calculus](/questions/tagged/matrix-calculus) [scalar-fields](/questions/tagged/scalar-fields) [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)

Answer (score 1):

By brute force:
$$a^tXb = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^m a_j x_{ij}b_i,$$
$$\frac{\partial a^tXb}{\partial x_{ij}} = a_jb_i.$$