# Gradient of $M \mapsto x^T M x$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Suppose we have a linear scalar field $f : \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$ f(M) := x^T M x $$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. What is the gradient of $f(M)$ with respect to $M$? I think it is $xx^T$, but why?

Comment: Since $f$ is linear, its differential is equal to $f$...

Comment: Can you write down the calculation for me?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2189207/339790)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strategy is to write the expression as a scalar using index notation, take the
derivative, and re-write in matrix form.

Note that to write the function as a summation of matrices we have to write just one scalar as a matrix multiplication because the function is scalar:
$$
f(M)= [x^TMx]_{11}= \sum_i x_{i1}[Mx]_{i1}
$$
At first summation, we have $x_{i1}$ because we have $x^T$ as the first term.

Now expand $[Mx]_{i1}$
$$
f(M)= [x^TMx]_{11}= \sum_i x_{i1}\sum_j M_{ij}x_{j1}=\sum_i \sum_j x_{i1} M_{ij}x_{j1}
$$

Now take the derivative with respect to $M_{ij}$

$$
\frac{\partial f(M)}{\partial M_{ij}}=\sum_i \sum_j x_{i1}x_{j1}
$$

Looking at the indices, we can see that

$$
\sum_i \sum_j x_{i1}x_{j1}=\sum_i \sum_j x_{j1}x_{i1}=[xx^T]_{ji}
$$

Therefore,

$$
\frac{\partial f(M)}{\partial M_{ij}}=xx^T
$$

Answer (score 6):

$$
f(M)=\sum_{i,j}x_iM_{i,j}x_j.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{\partial f(M)}{\partial M_{i,j}} = x_ix_j = (xx^T)_{i,j}.
$$

Comment: Could you explain the last step?

Comment: What is $xx^T$ for you?