# Differentiating a column with respect to a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, tensors

Let $\mathbf{X} = [\mathbf{x}_1 | ... | \mathbf{x}_n]$ be a $m \times n$ matrix.
I would like to differentiate $\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{e}_i$ (where $\mathbf{e}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ is the unit vectors with $1$ on the $i$th place and $0$'s in the rest) with respect to $\mathbf{X}$. Then
$$
d\mathbf{x}_i = d(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{e}_i) = (\mathbf{X} + d\mathbf{X})\mathbf{e}_i - \mathbf{X}\mathbf{e}_i = (d\mathbf{X})\mathbf{e}_i
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}_i}{d\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{e}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}
$$
However, I suspect that is not consistent dimension-wise. For example: $f(\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{a} \mathbf{x}_i$ where $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}$ then simply using the result above
$$
\frac{d f(\mathbf{X})}{d\mathbf{X}} = \frac{d(\mathbf{a}\mathbf{x}_i)}{d\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{a} \mathbf{e}_i \implies \mbox{Dimensions mismatch!}
$$
since $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}$ and $\mathbf{e}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$.

How to fix this issue? An idea is to put a pseudo identity matrix
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}_i}{d\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{I}_{m \times n} \mathbf{e}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}
$$
such that $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{X} \circ \mathbf{I}_{m \times n}$ with Hadamard product. But is this the right way to go?

Comment: You need a 3-d matrix.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: The input is an $m \times n$ matrix. The output is an $m$-vector. There are $m$ derivatives — the derivative of each entry of the output with respect to the $m \times n$ matrix input. An $m \times n \times m$ "matrix" is needed. It would be easier if you asked for each of these $m$ derivatives.

Comment: If you consider the function that extracts a single entry (rather than a single column), then take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189946/339790).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\E{{\cal E}}$Use
$(\star)$ to denote the dyadic product
and a colon to denote the double-dot product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\Gamma &= A\star B \quad&\implies\quad
\Gamma_{ijk\ell} = A_{ij}B_{k\ell} \\
Y &= \Gamma:X \quad&\implies\quad
Y_{ij}= \sum_{k,\ell}\;\Gamma_{ijk\ell}X_{k\ell} \\
}$$
First, rewrite the linear equation $b=Xa\,$ using index notation
$$\eqalign{
b_i &= X_{ik}\,a_k \\
 &= \delta_{ij} X_{jk}\,a_k \\
 &= \delta_{ij} a_k\,X_{jk} \\
}$$
where $\delta_{ik}$ is a [Kronecker delta;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) these are simply the components of the identity matrix $I$.

Rewrite the linear equation using the dyadic and double-dot products, and then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
b &= (I\star a):X \\
db &= (I\star a):dX \\
\p{b}{X} &= (I\star a) \\
}$$
Finally, substitute $(a=e_i,\;b=Xa=x_i)\;$ to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\p{x_i}{X} &= I\star e_i \\
}$$

Comment: So this tensor dimension are $m \times n \times m \times n$? How to explicitly compute the matrix products involving it? e.g. $A E B^T$?

Comment: $\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Would 
it help to show the result in component form?
$$
\left(\p{x_i}{X}\right)_{jk\ell} =
\left({\cal E}e_i^T\right)_{jk\ell} = 
{\cal E}_{jk\ell i} = \delta_{j\ell} \delta_{ki}
$$

Comment: Yes. But can you define the products $X \mathcal{E} Y$ and $\mathcal{E} : X$ in components form?

Comment: Also, des $\mathcal{E} X = \sum_l \mathcal{E}_{i,j,k,l} X_{l,n} = \sum_l \delta_{i,k}\delta_{j,l} X_{l,n} = \delta_{i,k} X_{j,n}$?

Comment: Yes that's right, juxtaposition _implies_ a single-dot product in matrix notation. And the colon notation is an explicit double-dot product $$\eqalign{ {\cal E}X &= &\sum_\ell {\cal E}_{ijk\ell}X_{\ell p} \\{\cal E}:X &= \sum_k &\sum_\ell {\cal E}_{ijk\ell}X_{k\ell} \\ }$$

Comment: You might want to response also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4085534/operations-between-rank-4-tensor-and-matrices-definitions-and-computations

Comment: I updated the answer to eliminate the need for the $\cal E$ tensor. Hopefully, it's easier to understand.