# Gradient of linear scalar field with respect to matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I am following the book [Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://mml-book.github.io) to study the math necessary to understand machine learning papers. On page 158, the authors list these results about gradients of scalar fields with respect to matrices and vectors:

$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{a}^T \tag{1} $$

$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T \tag{2} $$

The book follows numerator layout.

I am slightly confused about the dimension of the results. Assume $\mathbf{a} \in \Bbb R^n$, $\mathbf{X} \in \Bbb R^{n\times m}$, $\mathbf{b} \in \Bbb R^m$, where $m = 1$ in the first equation. Yet the dimension of the first one is $m\times n\ (m = 1)$ while the dimension of the second one is $n \times m$. Why is that?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2189207/339790)

Comment: I don't understand why the authors transposed $\bf a$ in (1). However, I did not look at their definition of gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the answer from Ted is wrong...

In both cases you consider, you have a scalar function $\phi$
that takes either a vector or a matrix in input
and returns a scalar.
Using the Frobenius inner product (denoted by the colon operator),
computing a vector/matrix derivative
is nothing more than expressing
the differential form of $\phi$
in a special form and proceed by identification.

For vector-valued functions,
write $d\phi$ as
$d\phi = 
\mathbf{a}:d\mathbf{x}
$. By identification,
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
\mathbf{a}
$$

For matrix-valued functions,
write $d\phi$ as
$d\phi =  
\mathbf{A}:d\mathbf{X}
$. By identification,
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
=
\mathbf{A}
$$

So in your first example,
$\phi(\mathbf{x})
= \mathbf{a}: \mathbf{x}$
Thus $d\phi=\mathbf{a}: d\mathbf{x}$
and the derivative is the vector
$\mathbf{a}$.

In the second example
$\phi(\mathbf{X})
= \mathbf{a}: \mathbf{Xb}
= \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T: \mathbf{X}
$
Thus $d\phi=\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T: d\mathbf{X}$
and the derivative is the matrix
$\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T$.

Comment: Yet, in the book, allegedly, vector $\bf a$ was transposed.

Comment: I think the book has some inconsistencies... The two results obtained using the differential method are definitely consistent. I think it is 'safer' to think that the derivative has the same shape as the denominator in this case.

Comment: Machine learning books can be shockingly sloppy.